# Awstats over cgi does not show historical data

Tags: cgi, awstats

I have awstats for several virtualhosts, runned via cgi. One of them does not show historical data. It shows just data for this month. But runned on command line generates html with correct data.

```
/usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=www.example.org -year=2013 -month=03 -output  > stats-2013-03.html
```

I don't have any historical apache logs, I have awstats logs for this virtualhost back to several years (awstats122009.www.example.org.txt, ...).

Any hint what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in setting of own virtual host which lead to wrong url parametr config (so data could not be found - assumed to be awstats122012.stats.example.org.txt instead of awstats122012.example.org.txt).